# Controlling jQuery tabs with a previous/next button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am having quite a battle controlling tabs through a button click function. I want the user to go through tabs in order. Each tab has a different html form. So the buttons provide also a validation. But the main problem is the next & previous buttons are not functioning at all. How come the button is not changing tabs at all?

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".nexttab").click(function() {
        var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
    });

    $(".backtab").click(function() {
        var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected - 1);
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="convertThis">
    <div id="tabs">
        <div href="#a" rel="a" title="./images/icons/category1.png">Category 1</div>
        <div href="#b" rel="b" title="./images/icons/category2.png">Category 2</div>
    </div>

    <div id="divs">
        <div id="a">
               <form action="" method="post">
                 CATEGORY 1 FORM CONTENT
                    <div class="tabController">
                        <div class="tabNext">
                        <input type="button" class="nexttab" value="Next &gt;&gt;" name="submit" id="submit" style="background: #EFEFEF; float:right;"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div>
        <div id="b">
             <form action="" method="post" id="post2">
                    CATEGORY 2 FORM CONTENT
                 <div class="tabController">
                     <div class="tabBack">
                        <input type="button" class="backtab" value="&lt;&lt; Previous" name="submit2" id="submit2" style="background: #EFEFEF;"/>
                     </div>
                 <div class="tabNext">
                        <input type="button" class="nexttab" value="Next &gt;&gt;" name="submit" id="submit" style="background: #EFEFEF; float:right;"/>
                </div>
                </div>
           </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Added jquery-ui-* tags, tabs are not natively supported in JQuery alone.

Comment: I don't think nesting `<input>`s in an `<a>` is even valid HTML...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your buttons are of type "`submit`" and they force a refresh of the page? Try to change them to `<input type="button" ... />`

Also, get rid of the `<a>` tags around the buttons.

Use either a button `<input type='button'>` OR a link `<a href='...'>text</a>`, there's no point in having a link wrapping a button.

Comment: @Craino, thanks for the tip. After making the change to a type=button it is still not working.

Comment: @jonthecoder2346 You have to eliminate the `<a>` tag but give its class (like `tabNext`) to the button too